# Hiding second level dependencies in shared libraries on Linux with NetBeans

Tags: c++, gcc, netbeans, shared-libraries, netbeans-7

Let me explain my problem: I wrote a shared library libMyLib.so that uses OpenCV libopencv_core.so.

When I write an application that uses my library (*libMyLib.so*) I would like to hide the use of OpenCV library (i.e. an implicit link) but I'm not able. I have to link explicitly to libopencv_core.so too.

What should I do? Is it possible or I have to link OpenCV statically to my own library to hide it?

I'm using NetBeans 7.3.1 with gcc 4.7.3 and ld 2.23.2.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible to link the OpenCV library statically.  I don't think there's much that can be done to completely hide the OpenCV library symbols in a process that loads the shared library.  The following options to `ld` should work:

```
ld ... -static -lopencv_core -Bdynamic ...
```

If calling from `cc`, then it's like this:

```
gcc ... -Wl,-static,-lopencv_core,-Bdynamic ...
```

Another possibility is using dynamic loading of the library with dlopen() and finding symbols with dlsym().  This may work to hide the rest of the library's symbols.  Here's an online version of the manpage for those: http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen.

Comment: Well I think the solution to my problem would be to fully encapsulate OpenCV by statically linking to libopencv_core.a, etc. That is not a problem but I'm still curious: my lib.so still need system libs.so for sure and I don't have to link explicitly to them... ;-)

Comment: That's true.  Do you want to hide the symbols from those as well?

Comment: Yes! Actually I want to hide the existence of OpenCV. I don't know the programmer has to know about OpenCV when he uses my lib. After reading your answer and thinking a little, I beleive I'll rebuild OpenCV as static and like these libs this way.